# C# gRpc TLS client host name

Tags: c#, grpc

I have a C# gRpc server and a client working over TLS using mutual authentication by creating my own certificates. I now wanted to make sure the client is certified with a specific certificate. I can find the IP address in `ServerCallContext.Peer`, but I'm unable to find the certificate information in the context.

I'm also surprised to see the `ServerCallContext.AuthContext.IsPeerAuthenticated` field return `false`, maybe because I created the certificates myself ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was using `false` for `forceClientAuth`, after I set it `true` the information is available.

```
SslServerCredentials(IEnumerable<KeyCertificatePair> keyCertificatePairs, string rootCertificates, bool forceClientAuth);
```